# Creating Excel sheet with Excel workbook name using Java with webdriver

Tags: java, excel, webdriver, jxl

While creating excel file in output stream class, sheet is creating with Excel workbook name.
The code I developed is as follows. Please let me know the correct code to meet my requirement.

```
FileInputStream fi =new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\ode\\resources\\Admin_Login.xls");
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("AdminUserLogin");
    Sheet sh1 = wb.getSheet("FieldValidations_Zip");
    System.out.println("<><><><><>   "+sh1.getName());

    //Create the Result xls file
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("Admin_Login_Results_"+cdate+".xls");
    //FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\ode\\resources\\output\\Admin_Login_Results_"+cdate+".xls");
    WritableWorkbook wwb = Workbook.createWorkbook(fo);
    WritableSheet ws = wwb.createSheet("FieldValidations_Zip", 0);
    Thread.sleep(Admin_zipcode);
```

Help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the this issue by changing the pointer to other sheet then it worked fine for me.